# Difficult integral in terms of generalized functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I am struggling to evaluate the following integral

\begin{align}
   I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\kappa_0\sqrt{r^2+t^2}}}{(r^2+t^{2})^{3/4}}e^{-ik t} d t.
\end{align}

I have tried standard method of residues but that doesnt seem to work as the result comes out as zero due to the fact that the $t\pm ir$ factor doesn't cancel completely with that of the denominator. I have a feeling this integral can be expressed in in terms of generalized functions.

Comment: The presence of $\sqrt{r^2+t^2}$ suggests for a substitution of the form $t=r\sinh x$. However, when integrating a function containing a non-trivial or irreducible expression of the form $e^{\cosh x}$, the only known solutions are those in terms of [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).